# How to set the CLASSPATH to import jar package in a short format

Tags: java

Can this way import multiple jars?

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\dependency\*;C:\location\*
```

Is this means all jars below the **dependency** is imported?

Comment: The `CLASSPATH` environment variable has been deprecated since Java 5 (or maybe even earlier). Don't use it. Use an explicit `-cp ...` parameter for `java.exe` The behaviour of the parameter is explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#JSWOR586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcards are allowed in the latest Java 6. See the document for details:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

---

Let's take a look at this example

`java -classpath "./libs/*" Test`

The `*` here refers to all jar files in the LIBS directory. You can't write `java -classpath "./libs/*. jar"` test like this

If there are both jar files and class files in the LIBS directory, we all want to reference them, so we need to write

`java -classpath "./libs/*;./libs/" Test`

Note: in Windows system, the separator is`;` in UNIX system, the separator is`:`

Note that `LIBS/*` does not contain jar files in subdirectories under LIBS directory, such as `LIBS/folder1/a.jar`

If you want to include subdirectories, you need to be clear about them, such as

`java -cp "./libs/*;./libs/folder1/*" Test`

Comment: @Dennis Lee  If I have solved your problem, please set my reply as this problem's best answer, if not, please continue to reply to me.